Why does npm http-server not work on Ubuntu 24.04 LTS except on port 8080
I installed npm using the nvm as shown in the official site.
# installs nvm (Node Version Manager)
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.7/install.sh | bash
# download and install Node.js (you may need to restart the terminal)
nvm install 22
# verifies the right Node.js version is in the environment
node -v # should print `v22.5.1`
# verifies the right npm version is in the environment
npm -v # should print `10.8.2`

I ran npm install http-server -g to install http-server globally.
And then, I ran http-server -p1000, but it gave the error:
node:events:498
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EACCES: permission denied 0.0.0.0:1000
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (node:net:1880:21)
    at listenInCluster (node:net:1959:12)
    at doListen (node:net:2133:7)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (node:net:1938:8)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  code: 'EACCES',
  errno: -13,
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: '0.0.0.0',
  port: 1000
}

Node.js v22.5.1

However, when I ran http-server ./ and http-server -p8080, there were no issues. So it looks like the error occurs only all ports except port 8080.
What did I do wrong?
Has anyone had this kind of issue?
What should I do to make my server run on any port?
An answer to this question will be highly appreciated.

I have found the solution. Ports <1024 are the only ports that do not work.

That's likely, because the ports below 1024 are privileged. So you have to open them as root, and after that drop the privileges (at best).

I didn't know this because I am new to ubuntu
